# How to debug in visual studio when API project is installed so far?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have API project in my solution (Visual Studio) but I can't debug it and change code because it is installed in Windows. This dll is in GAC. I do not want to uninstall this API and I want to have possibility to change code of this API and trying to debug it without removing it from GAC. Is it possible?

Comment: No you can not debug changed code with existing dll without updating it.

Comment: You need a matching pdb and source code for your saved in GAC dll.

Comment: Can't I build this project with some kind of condition and after installation I will have possibility to debug it and changing the code?

Comment: I can change this API and maybe set some condition in this project that after installation I can debug my project without changing namespace  maybe. I've read something about bind redirection but still I could not find a solution how to implement this. I can't believe it isn't possible. Please help.

Comment: @Sebastian Straszewski, Do you just want to debug the executable? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0bxe8ytt.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 or you could debug it remotely if you couldn't change it in your local Environment, so you could change and debug it in your remote machine.